# C# - What does the last while loop and 'var x' do?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, var

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main()
        {            
            var entry = 0;
            try {
                Console.Write("Enter the number of times to print \"Yay!\": ");
                var entryParsed = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (entryParsed < 0) 
                {
                    Console.Write("You must enter a positive number.");
                }  
                else 
                {
                    entry += entryParsed;
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.Write("You must enter a whole number.");
            }

            var x = 0;
            while (true) 
            {
                if (x < entry) 
                {
                    Console.Write("Yay!");
                    x++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the few last lines of code, I do not understand what the 'var x' and the while loop does or represents. This code sample is from a Treehouse challenge but how does 'var x' make the program work as intended? Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: it will loop printing 'yay' entry times. A for loop would have been clearer

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code, and you'll see exactly what it does.

Comment: x is a counter, incremented after each printout of 'Yay'. After x = entry, the logic in the while loop will force it to exit (break). You can use a simple for loop instead if you find the while loop logic is a bit complicated.

Comment: `var x` is an implicitly assigned type counter variable, it automatically assign x to type `int`. The while loop can be substituted with this for loop to print the text in (x - 1) times: `for (var x = 0; x < entry; x++)`.

Answer (score 2):

The [var](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) keyword in C# means "infer the type".

```
var x = 0; //Means the same thing as latter 
int x = 0; //The compiler actually CONVERTS the former to this in an early pass when it strips away syntactic sugar
```

The code you've posted is very... suggestive of a beginner. That last block is a [for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) loop. Irrefutably. Any alternative is objectively inferior.

Here's an alternative way to write it. Admittedly hilarious overkill, but you get the idea:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Example
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int entry = CollectUserInput<int>("Enter the number of times to print \"Yay!\": ",
                (int x) => x > 0, "Please enter a positive number: ");

            for (int i=0; i<entry; i++) {
                Console.Write("Yay!");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Prompts user for console input; reprompts untils correct type recieved. Returns input as specified type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Display message to prompt user for input.</param>
        private static T CollectUserInput<T>(string message = null)
        {
            if (message != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
            while (true)
            {
                string rawInput = Console.ReadLine();
                try
                {
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(rawInput, typeof(T));
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please input a response of type: " + typeof(T).ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Prompts user for console input; reprompts untils correct type recieved. Returns input as specified type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Display message to prompt user for input.</param>
        /// <param name="validate">Prompt user to reenter input until it passes this validation function.</param>
        /// <param name="validationFailureMessage">Message displayed to user after each validation failure.</param>
        private static T CollectUserInput<T>(string message, Func<T, bool> validate, string validationFailureMessage = null)
        {
            var input = CollectUserInput<T>(message);
            bool isValid = validate(input);
            while (!isValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(validationFailureMessage);
                input = CollectUserInput<T>();
                isValid = validate(input);
            }
            return input;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah cuz all this crazy ass code helps me understand as a beginner xD

Answer (score 0):

`var` is just a syntactic shortcut to avoid explicitly defining the type of `x` - the compiler can determine what type `x` is because it is implicit in the value being assigned.

As for your loop, it could be simplified to this:

```
var x = 0;

while (x++ < entry) {
    Console.Write("Yay!");
}
```

Normally you would avoid an explicit `while(true)` loop because as your code gets more complicated it raises the risk that your exit condition inside the loop is never met and you end up with an endless loop - it is better practice to have the exit expression clearly visible rather than hide it somewhere inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

the idiomatic way to do the same thing is

```
for(int x = 0; x < entry;x++)
{
   Console.Write("Yay!");
}
```